# android - how to display data from one activity to another activity by query in SQLite DataBase table? - Stack Overflow

Tags: xml, database, sqlite, listview, android-studio

I have done following coding for retrieving data's from database and want to display in the Edit Text view to another activity. The following code is for the fetching data..

```
   String fetch_data(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase sq = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String q = "SELECT "+TAB_NAME+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+TAB_ID+" = "+id;

    Cursor c = sq.rawQuery(q, null);

    String s = "";
    c.moveToFirst();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        s = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TAB_NAME+""));
    }

    return s;

}
```

The following code is for the showing the data in this activity..

```
t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    final MyDBFunction obj = new MyDBFunction(getApplicationContext());
    int req_pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("MyKEY",999);
    t1.setText(obj.fetch_data(req_pos+1));
    t1.setSelection(t1.getText().length());
```

and this code is from the activity where i am trying to get the data..

```
l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);


    MyDBFunction mf = new MyDBFunction(getApplicationContext());

    final String[] data = mf.broadData();

    l.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.lvlayout,R.id.text1,data));

    l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked On "+data[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowInfo.class);
            i.putExtra("MyKEY",position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

but i can't get the data where is the problem???

Answer (score 0):

Where is your SQLite Database stored? Probably it is in the private storage of the first activity?

Maybe you can have a look at:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: i can retrieve all the data but i can't show one particular data that has been clicked from the list view.. and i couldn't found out where is the problem ???